# Extracting values into a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in a dataframe as follows:

```
Data 
[special_request=nowhiterice, waiter=Janice]
[allegic=no, waiter=Janice, tip=20]
[allergic=no, tip=20]
[special_request=nogreens]
```

May I know how could I make it such that one data = 1 column ?

```
special_request   allegic   waiter   tip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a Dictionary by splitting the elements of your series and build your Dataframe from it (`s` being your column here):

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([['special_request=nowhiterice', 'waiter=Janice'],
['allegic=no', 'waiter=Janice', 'tip=20'],
['allergic=no', 'tip=20'],
['special_request=nogreens']])

df = pd.DataFrame([dict(e.split('=') for e in row) for row in s])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  special_request  waiter allegic  tip allergic
0     nowhiterice  Janice     NaN  NaN      NaN
1             NaN  Janice      no   20      NaN
2             NaN     NaN     NaN   20       no
3        nogreens     NaN     NaN  NaN      NaN
```

Edit: if the column values are actual strings, you first should split your string (also stripping `[`, `]`and whitespaces):

```
s = pd.Series(['[special_request=nowhiterice, waiter=Janice]',
'[allegic=no, waiter=Janice, tip=20]',
'[allergic=no, tip=20]',
'[special_request=nogreens]'])

df = pd.DataFrame([dict(map(str.strip, e.split('=')) for e in row.strip('[]').split(',')) for row in s])
print(df)
```

Comment: Just curious why if i use `l=df['Data ].tolist()` and `s=pd.Series(l)` there will be "ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required" error despite both solution being similar? Any workarounds if I were dealing the same with a larger dataset?

Comment: Maybe your column elements are not formatted like I assumed they were. Are they string or list? Please edit your question so that we can recreate the Data column with the right type.

Comment: my example could be found here https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1glWzku4Mo5-nPszhI19Gz8ik8YhWfL08?usp=sharing im just curious to use another method but it didnt work

Comment: A bit late but the accepted answer shows you how to split your string to get a list (also stripping whitespaces from extracted strings). You can use the same with the DataFrame constructor instead of json_normalize and apply to get the same result

Comment: could you show me how?

Comment: Sure, I updated my answer! Please consider upvoting useful answers :-)

Comment: Btw, the steps `l=df['Data'].tolist()` and `s=pd.Series(l)` can be reduced to `s=df['Data']`

Answer (score 0):

You can split the column value of string type into dict then use `pd.json_normalize` to convert dict to columns.

```py
df_ = pd.json_normalize(df['Data'].apply(lambda x: dict([map(str.strip, i.split('=')) for i in x.strip("[]").split(',')])))
```

```
print(df_)

  special_request  waiter allegic  tip allergic
0     nowhiterice  Janice     NaN  NaN      NaN
1             NaN  Janice      no   20      NaN
2             NaN     NaN     NaN   20       no
3        nogreens     NaN     NaN  NaN      NaN
```

Comment: I tried at it returned ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Comment: That works. Thank you. What if [special_request=nogreens] is a list instead of a string? Any workarounds?

Comment: @KusisiKarem It couldn't be list since it doesn't meet Python syntax.